# How to make hover-active whole <li>,with <a> and <img> tags

Tags: html, css, linked-list, cursor

I have this HTML and CSS list structure :

```css
.mylist-group{
  padding-left: 0;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
      list-style:none;
 }
.mylist-group-item{
 
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height:134px;
 }

.mylist-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
.list-group-item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

 
.mylist-group-item  img{
float:right;
margin :5px 5px 5px 10px;
}

.mylist-group-item a{
float:right;
margin :50px 40px 0 0;
text-decoration: none;
 color: #555555;
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mylist-group">
  <li class="mylist-group-item">
   <img src="images/f6.jpg" class="img-rounded">
   <a href="#"> گالری کیک</a>
   </li>
  <li class="mylist-group-item">
  <img src="images/f6.jpg" class="img-rounded">
    <a href="#"> گالری کیک</a>
  </li>
   <li class="mylist-group-item">
    <img src="images/f6.jpg" class="img-rounded">
     <a href="#"> گالری کیک</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem is, that if I move cursor into the `<li>` are, the link is still not active, I have to move cursor on the exact link.

I would like to achieve to have an active link if I move cursor on the li tag, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to wrap the contents of each list item by an `a` element having desired height/padding/etc.

But without altering the markup, it is still possible (somehow) to expand the clickable area.

We can `display` the `a` elements as `block`s and give `overflow: hidden` to them in order not to overlap the floats.

Then add a proper `padding`/`line-height` (for vertical alignment) to them in order to achieve the goal, as follows:

```css
.mylist-group{
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  list-style:none;
}

.mylist-group-item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  height:134px;
}

.mylist-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}
.list-group-item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}


.mylist-group-item  img{
  float:right;
  margin :5px 5px 5px 10px;
}

.mylist-group-item a{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555555;
  display: block;
  line-height: 16px;
  padding: 59px 0;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mylist-group">
  <li class="mylist-group-item">
    <img src="images/f6.jpg" class="img-rounded">
    <a href="#"> گالری کیک</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mylist-group-item">
    <img src="images/f6.jpg" class="img-rounded">
    <a href="#"> گالری کیک</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mylist-group-item">
    <img src="images/f6.jpg" class="img-rounded">
    <a href="#"> گالری کیک</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

What about something like

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/f6.jpg" class="img-rounded"> گالری کیک</a>
```

?

**Update:**
This

```
<a href="#">
    <li class="mylist-group-item">
         <img src="images/f6.jpg" class="img-rounded"> 
         گالری کیک
    </li>
</a>
```

wasn't the best idea, as Hashem pointed out in the comments.

Comment: List items cannot have parent element other than list elements (`ul`, `ol`).

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the whole li into the href like this and change the "a" for a "span"

```
    <a href="#">
        <li class="mylist-group-item">
            <img src="images/f6.jpg" class="img-rounded" />
            <span> گالری کیک</span>
        </li>
    </a>
```

You'll need to change your css instead of

```
.mylist-group-item a {
    ...
}
```

You need to have

```
.mylist-group-item span {
    ...
}
```

Comment: List items cannot have parent element other than list elements (`ul`, `ol`).